# Enabling OverlayFS on Raspbian OS prevents eth1 from working (USB to Ethernet dongle is plugged)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ethernet, overlayfs

I am working with Raspberry Pis running on Raspbian OS. For a Pi a friend had configured, we are using a USB to Ethernet adapter and to protect the SD card we have Overlay and Write protection both enabled. It does not cause any issues at all, eth1 is set to the static 192.164.64.254 and the USB to Ethernet adapter does its job normally.

Now I am setting up an other Pi, same OS (except this is a 64 bits version), same kind of USB to Ethernet adapter connected to a USB port. Whenever I enable Overlay FS and reboot, eth1 disappears as if the dongle was not connected, please see the screenshot. [This is whenever OverlayFS is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df5su.png)
Command line prompts back "cannot find device eth1".

Whenever I disable Overlay and reboot, everything is back to normal, eth1 is working (IP is 192.168.64.145), I also submit the screenshot here.[This is with OverlayFS disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyVt1.jpg)

If anyone has any idea why this happens or any suggestion on what should be tested to investigate further, I will be grateful.

Kind regards,
Olivier

I am not sure what to try, changing from one IP to an other?